# Visual editor on front-end call not working properly

Tags: editor

Since the upgrade of WP to 4.9.4, I am having a problem with WP's native editor in the front-end. The Text option are working but for Visual option, no buttons appearing and the texts are white.
[image: White texts[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umvz6.png)

I tried to install Tinymce Advanced but still it behaves the same. I even tried to deactivate all of my plugins still no luck. I tried to downgrade up to WP 4.7 but it seems it's not on jQuery problem.

Somebody experience the same?

Below is the code I used to call for the editor in front end;

```
<?php 

                        $settings = array(
                            'wpautop' => true,
                            'postContent' => 'content',
                            'media_buttons' => false,
                            'tinymce' => array(
                                'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,underline,blockquote,separator,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,undo,redo,link,unlink,fullscreen',
                                'theme_advanced_buttons2' => 'pastetext,pasteword,removeformat,|,charmap,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo',
                                'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
                                'theme_advanced_buttons4' => ''
                            ),
                            'quicktags' => array(
                                'buttons' => 'b,i,ul,ol,li,link,close'
                            )
                        );

                        wp_editor( $postContent, 'postContent', $settings );

                    ?>
```

Comment: the general rule of thumb, if you ask about something that "is not working" without adding the relevant code, it is like you didn't ask at all. Edit your question, add the relevant code and **all** debugging efforts you have done trying to debug it yourself, include relevant browser and server error log entries.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Added the code to call the editor. Thanks!

Comment: code seems ok, any console errors? have you verified the relevant JS files are loaded?

Comment: .... have you checked that you do not have multiple elements with IDs with the same value (postContent) on the page?

Comment: I checked all relevant script that needs to be loaded, it seems to be okay and the element postContent is unique hence no problem with that as well. Would it be on the current jquery library problem?

Comment: it is almost for sure an JS/HTML problem. usually this happens if you have some additional script on the page that raises an exception that is not handled

Comment: I tried to add this line [code] define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);[/code] in my wp-config.php as I read in some forums but it didn't work for me. To see a clearer idea, I created a page in my site with the editor: http://lamyerda.ph/editor-sample/

Comment: what is on you test page and what you posted here do not seem to be the same. If you do not need the text part of the editor, I fail to see any real problem at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74595/discussion-between-paolo-medina-and-mark-kaplun).